# Persisting the contents of NSCache

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nscache

I am using NSCache to store the webData.

```
 webData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[cache setObject:webData forKey:urlString];
```

The cache will be exist only when my application is running. I want to persist the contents of cache though the application is quit. Writing the contents into the disk is one of the way.Is there any other way ? if not what is efficient way to write the cache into the disk?

Comment: See my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43026958/746347) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43026939/746347).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save NSCache Contents to Disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542707/save-nscache-contents-to-disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **CoreData** as CoreData does is persistency of object graphs with purging and pruning capabilities.

Refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) for tutorial

Comment: I am not used coreData yet . so i am not comfortable in it. also Can i add core data in my existing application.

Comment: ok i will. But how can add core data in existing application?

Comment: [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1) link [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project) link [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908836/iphone-add-core-data-to-existing-project) link

Answer (score 0):

You can choose [TMCache](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache) as it has ability of persistence.